# Python Multiplication with 2 decimal number as product result

Tags: python

Is there a way to this simple equation? I'm getting as a product result : `858.2999999999999682365192655`

the simple equation is this:

```
from decimal import Decimal

 x = Decimal(57220) * Decimal(0.03)
 y = x / Decimal(2)
 print(y)
```

The expected answer should be 858.30
Also tried this but it rounds this off to 858.00

```
  x = Decimal(57220) * Decimal(0.03)
  y = x / Decimal(2)
  z = round(y, 2)
  print(z)
```

I'm really sorry I'm just a beginner here in python

BTW I'm using 3.6 version of python

Edited : I'm sorry it should be 57220 :(

Comment: On a calculator, the result comes to 858. How did you get 858.30?

Comment: It's exact 358.0 on calculator

Comment: I'm sorry it should be 57220 :( my bad

Comment: If you want the full accuracy of `Decimal`, you must make sure that no values are even momentarily floats - `Decimal(0.03)` is not exactly 0.03, because there is no float with that exact value.  You should write that as `Decimal("0.03")`, so that Decimal can perform an exact conversion.

Comment: @jasonharper you should add that as an answer.  It actually answers the question

Comment: @Kaya3 provided the answer thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you get as a result makes sense and is not wrong.

```
57220 * 0.03 / 2 = (572.20 * 3) / 2 = 286.10 * 3 = 858.30
```

So, the answer you get from the following block of code makes sense as is supposed to be `858.30`.

```py
from decimal import Decimal

x = Decimal(57200) * Decimal(0.03)
y = x / Decimal(2)
# if you want to keep two places after the decimal
y = round(y,2)
print(y)
```

**Output**:

```
858.30
```

EDIT: Updated solution based on OP's feedback about a typo in the question.

Comment: I'm Sorry it should be 57220 :(

Comment: Ok. Solution's updated now to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Decimal. neither you have to convert to float. Make it simple and it will give exact answer. Thanks!!

```
x = 57220 * 0.03
y = x / 2
print(y)
```

Output:

```
858.3
```

Comment: Correct. Although i need to compare 2 values which need 2 decimal points (comparing money with 2 decimal) although thats a different story